# Python selectively writing specific statement

Tags: python, tweepy

The below def is working perfectly in cmd, but when writing to the file, it is only writing the second data.write statement. The first statement is definitely working, it is just not writing. Given the code is identical i can't figure out for the life of me what is wrong.

```
def follower_count(list1):
    for name in list1:
        name = '@' + name
        try:
            user = api.get_user(name)
            if user.followers_count < 5000:
                print ""
                print "FAILED TEST"
                print name
                print user.followers_count
                data.write(name + ": " + user.followers_count + "\n")
            else:
                print ""
                print name 
                print user.followers_count
        except: 
            print ""
            print "Error grabbing " + name
            data.write("Error Grabbing: " + name + "\n")
    return()
```

Comment: Is `data.write` a custom method, or a built-in?

Comment: If the `data.write` in the except block is executing, that means an error occurred. But you can't tell what kind of error occurred because you're catching the error and not displaying any information about it. If you delete the `try` and the `except` and the except block, what error message do you get?

Comment: data is the open file. thus the .write is a basic function. 

data = open('Data.txt', 'w+')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.write(name + ": " + user.followers_count + "\n")
```

This line will crash with `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` if `user.followers_count` is an integer.

Try using `str.format` to interpolate your strings.

```
data.write("{}: {}\n".format(name, user.followers_count))
```

---

Furthermore, you're making debugging much harder for yourself by not displaying any diagnostic information in your `except`. You know that an error occurred, but don't know anything about that error specifically. At the very least, you could do:

```
    except Exception as e: 
        print ""
        print "Error grabbing " + name
        data.write("Error Grabbing: " + name + "\n")
        data.write(e.message + "\n")
```

Which will at least tell you what the error message is.